# linux: why can't I search /sys/class but I can search /sys

Tags: linux, shell

I am having an odd error in my shell script. 
using this:

```
$find /sys/class/ -name temp -exec cat '{}' ';'
```

I get output of

```
77000
find: `/sys/kernel/debug': Permission denied
```

I only want the the 77000 to display however I cannot limit the search to the class subfolder for some reason.

```
$find /sys/class/ -name temp -exec cat '{}' ';'
```

Typing the above I don't get any result at all...

Weird eh?

Haha if anyone could clarify why this happens that would be awesome!

Comment: I think you may have made a copy-paste mistake in your first code example - shouldn't it be `$find /sys/ -name temp -exec cat '{}' ';'` ?

Comment: Learn about redirection, and use `2>/dev/null` if want to suppress the warning message.

Comment: There is no file named `temp` under /sys/class; hence no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find /sys -name temp -exec cat '{}' ';' 2> /dev/null`